# How can I change a tab without causing selectedIndexChange

Tags: angular, angular-material

I need to change a tab programmatically without firing the `selectedIndexChange` event.

I made a stackBlitz example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ujhwwv?file=src/app/app.component.ts). The related code is the following:

```html
<mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="tabIndex" (selectedIndexChange)="informChange($event)">
  <mat-tab label="Tab 1"></mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Tab 2"></mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Tab 3"></mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Tab 4"></mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Tab 5"></mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
<br>
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="goToTab3()">Change Tab</button>
```

With the respective class

```js
export class AppComponent {
  tabIndex = 0;

  goToTab3() {
    this.tabIndex = (this.tabIndex + 1) % 5;
  }

  informChange(tabIndex:number) {
    console.log(tabIndex);
  }
}
```

What I want is that the tab will change on every button click but the event handler that is attached to the `selectedIndexChange` event should not get executed.

So I need to distinguish between a tab click which in that case I *do* want the `selectedIndexChange` to fire, and between a change made by code (the button in this example but could be a change from another part such as a store/redux change) which in that case I dont want the `selectedIndexChange` to fire but only change the selected tab.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use another event, `focusChange`

```html
<mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="tabIndex" (focusChange)="informChange($event.index)">
```

Remember that you get a [MatTabChangeEvent](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api#MatTabChangeEvent) instead of an index in that case, so you need to use `$event.index` in order to get the particular index that you are after.

Comment: Wow. thank you so much. It is very strange that this option doesn't exist because there are a lot of scenarios where it is needed.

Comment: I suppose you could also listen for `focusChange` instead of `selectedIndexChange`; in that case the event will fire when focus is changed on a tab. That might be better suited for you?

Comment: I think so. I tell you what.. I will try both solutions tomorrow. if your seconds remark suits better then I will ask you to post it as an answer and mark it as solved. Otherwise I will mark your first answer as solving my problem.
Thank you so much dear friend

Comment: your second answer with focusChange solved the problem. Do you want to edit your answer and I will check it as solved?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jvqc7k?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: The `focusChange` event won't work correctly for accessibility, as keyboard focus triggers `focusChange` without the tab actually changing.

Answer (score 0):

I am surely not understanding your question fully. Remove the `(selectedIndexChange)`?

```
<mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="tabIndex">
    <mat-tab label="Tab 1"></mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Tab 2"></mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Tab 3"></mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Tab 4"></mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Tab 5"></mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: Ohhh I wasn't clear. I need to distinguish between a tab click which in that case I do want the selectedIndexChange to fire and between a change made by code (or ngrx store state in my case) which in that case I dont want the selectedIndexChange to get fire but only to change the selected tab

Comment: I get it!! It seems that the selectedIndexChange "event" isn't passing an event object per se. It is simply passing a number (the index). This makes it difficult as we only have a primitive type to work with in the method and therefore can't consider eventPreventDefault. The material tabs API docs https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#events only mention selectedTabChange and focusChange events and not selectedIndexChange. Can you use selectedTabChange  and/or focusChange along with "typeof" to identify source of "click"?

Comment: Thank you so much. 

Can you add an example? Is there a way to combine those 2 events into 1 event?

Answer (score 0):

app.component.html:

```
<mat-tab-group  [selectedIndex]="tabIndex" (focusChange)="informChange($event.index)">
      <mat-tab label="Tab 1"></mat-tab>
      <mat-tab label="Tab 2"></mat-tab>
      <mat-tab label="Tab 3"></mat-tab>
      <mat-tab label="Tab 4"></mat-tab>
      <mat-tab label="Tab 5"></mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
```

app.component.ts

```
tabIndex;

informChange(tabIndex: number) {

    console.log('tabIndex');
    console.log(tabIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See that, as you has not a [(ngModel)], the value of "tabIndex" don't change when you select a tab

```
<mat-tab-group mat-align-tabs="start" [selectedIndex]="tabIndex" 
                                      (selectedIndexChange)="informChange($event)">
```

So your function (informChange)

```
 tabIndex:number=0;
 informChange(event: any) {
    if (this.tabIndex != event) {
      console.log("from tab-click");
    } else
    {
       console.log("from .ts");
    } 
    this.tabIndex = event; //force the value to tabIndex
 }
```